# Microsoft Access - Combo box in subform base off masterform combo box

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a `Masterform`, which handles all the information header of a `ReceivingReport`. You must select a `PO Number` from a combo box, and fill out the necessaries information as well. Everything works fine up to this point.

My `subform` on the other hand works if I keep it very basic but I want my `second combo box` located in my `subform`; which is base off the `ID` from the `first combo box` in the `masterform` to display only items from the `PO Number ID`.

I know my `Query` isn't working, since its not even displaying a record. But I can't seem to understand how to pull the information from the `masterform` combo box to use it correctly to retrieve the correct `data`.

As you can see in the query image, I was using this to retrieve the bound column `PurchaseOrderID` from the `first combo box`.

`[Forms]![frm_addReceiveReportInformation].[Form]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]`

[image][image]

Comment: What is your query returning when you have made a selection in the combobox? (just the query, not your form)

Comment: Its returning no records.

Comment: I am wondering if your reference to your control on your subform is correct.

Comment: I been playing around with it, and I can't seem to figure out how to join the tables... I think that is my current problem. I tried multiple things and I can get records depending on small changes. But it is returning more records than I am expecting

Comment: the master link / child link keys are 100% correct. I can vouch on that.

Comment: Is your question about your query, or about your form displaying the filtered records?

Comment: The query for the subform combo box filtering the records depending on the masterform combo box.

Comment: Okay - we need to test your reference to the field then, because if it is returning more than expected then something isn't being filtered correctly. Create a new query only with `tbl_receivingReport` and select the `ID` field and a couple other fields from it. Set the filter like you currently have for `PurchaseOrderID`. Make a selection in your combobox and run the query. Do you get filtered results?

Comment: I didn't fallow your instruction to the penny. I didn't want to actually modify my forms since they are semi busted at the moment. But I did create a query and tested the records return. I was able to get the records I wanted for the majority of the way. `tbl_rawItemList` -> `tbl_rawMaterialInventory` -> 'tbl_receivingReport` -> `tbl_purchaseOrder`. I did the reserve path compare to my picture as you can see. But the second I combine `tbl_PODetails` with any path or with both path connected, it sends me hundreds of records. I can post a screenshot if needed

Comment: So it's an issue with a join. That was the next step. You need to realize what you are actually doing here. For EVERY `tbl_purchaseOrder.ID` in `tbl_PODetails`, you are returning records. You could try a right inner join from `tbl_purchaseOrder` to `tbl_PODetails`.

Comment: This may take time, it seem like its asking me to do a sub query. The error I am getting "`The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL statement.`"

Answer (score 0):

[Forms]![frm_addReceiveReportInformation].[Form]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]

should be

[Forms]![frm_addReceiveReportInformation]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]